# How can eating bacon not make me fat?

Tags: diet, fatty-acid-synthase

[This page](http://9gag.com/gag/agy2Lxx) says it won't.

This page says it's the carb again http://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-10454/in-defense-of-bacon-why-eating-fat-can-help-you-get-thin.html

I don't see how eating fat will not make me gain weight while eating carbohydrates will, since fat is made of, well, fat.

It says eating carbs will make us fat. How can this be? Is this true?

Comment: I changed your title and text so that your question is a bit clearer, hope that's okay.

Comment: Fat in your body and the fat you eat are two different things. All the fat in your body is synthesized--made by the body. Dietary fat is not absorbed by the body. In fact, fat that you eat cannot even pass through the intestinal walls. It has to be broken down into carboxylic acid and monoglyceride. Carbs make you fat because the liver turns them into triglycerides, which is white fat. The liver also turns carbs into cholesterol hardening your arteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question can also be said to be - how can the [Atkins diet work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atkins_diet)?

Atkins and other low carbohydrate diets sound counterintuitive.  They vary in details, but the basic theme is: cut back on carbohydrates - e.g. bread, sugar, fruit, pasta, milk etc etc.  But eat as much fat and protein as you like - e.g. steak, ham, bacon, eggs, cheese etc etc.

These diets really do work.  Our metabolism allows us to draw food from two sources.  Glucose or fat. (there is also something called glycogen, but that is only used short term and not relevant for diets long term).

It was known in the late 50s that our metabolism will to switch over consuming fat, allowing weight loss, only based on the amount of carbohydrates we consume. low carb diets initiate this change from glucose to fat metabolism because our bodies make the switch based only on the amount of glucose available in the blood.  Our bodies think we are starving even if we are gorging ourselves on food which is has little or no glycemic index.

Low carb diets are not a hoax or snake oil - they really work.  They can be a shock to the system and so one should discuss with your doctor before engaging them.

The first link you have is also true though.  Eating fat will usually just make you gain weight.  The low carb response has to be induced by basically removing all carbohydrates from the diet.  If you break the low carb regime and eat a large amount of carbs, the body will switch practically instantly out of starvation mode and also take in all the fats you're eating.  Lots of people on low carb diets can gain a lot of weight rapidly if they break the diet.

Comment: It is still unclear, why bodies in the "starvation mode" do not absorb the dietary fat.

Comment: yes it doesn't entirely make sense either.  it may be that when drawing on the fat metabolism that its rare to be consuming fat... so storing fat and metabolizing it at the same time may conflict somehow.